# ngChosen: How do I clear the selection?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-chosen

I am using `ngChosen` to populate a menu.  At some point in my control flow I want to deselect the selected element.  Let's say the select has an `ngModel` of "foo".

```
 <select chosen="" 
     data-ng-model="foo" 
     data-ng-options="thing.property for thing in things" 
     class="chosen-select input-md"></select>
```

I have tried

```
$scope.foo = "";
```

and

```
$scope.operation = null;
```

But neither has worked.  How do I deselect the current selection in `ngChosen`?

Comment: example plunker would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

Clear out the model value (like you already are), then trigger `chosen:updated` on the element.

```
$scope.foo = "";
$('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
```

The caveat here is that Angular will first need to apply the changes you make to `foo` before you can trigger the event.

The **incorrect** way to do this would be to call `$scope.apply()` to force Angular to "go ahead and apply those changes to the DOM".

```
app.controller('MyController', [function() {
  $scope.actionToTake = function(){
    $scope.foo = "";
    $scope.apply();
    $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
  }
}
```

The correct way to handle this is to use the `$timeout` service. This will ensure the `$scope.apply()` has successfully been called and completed before the event is triggered.

```
app.controller('MyController', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  $scope.actionToTake = function(){
    $scope.foo = "";
    $timeout(function(){
      $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: `allow-single-deselect="true"`

```
<select chosen="" 
     data-ng-model="foo" 
     data-ng-options="thing.property for thing in things" 
     allow-single-deselect="true"
     class="chosen-select input-md"></select>
```

this will enable an option in the control to remove the selection

[you can see here how the control looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QXFX.png)

By doing this, when the remove option is activated, the model is also cleared.